# Microphone noise only when talking via Skype or VoIp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, kubuntu

I am using Kubuntu 12.10. I wanted to remove the fan sound from the microphone, since Samsung designers put the microphone on the keyboard and it records almost everything. I spoilt the settings but now cannot revert it back.

Under windows it was using a proprietary drive and these noises were not existed, but now I have a noise (its like bee whizzling) only when talking with Skype to VOIP software. Also noises still continues.

Do you have any idea to remove this bee whizzling?